# Undelared identifier on main form delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

I get the "Undeclared identifier"  in a pprocedure I created called submit.

```
procedure submit;
begin
if ebMain.Text='exit' then
fmMain.Close;
end;
```

Really simple. The compiler tells me ebMain is undeclared. I ca  fix this by putting "fmMain." in front of it but I never had to do this in delphi 7.The edit box(ebMain)  is on the main form(fmMain). The procedure header is placed just under the "uses". What's wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`submit()` is not a member of your `TfrmMain` class, so it does not know what `ebMain` is.  You need to either:

1) make `submit()` be a member of your form's class (which you should do anyway because all it is doing is accessing members of `TfrmMain`):

```
procedure TfrmMain.submit; 
begin 
  if ebMain.Text='exit' then 
    Close; 
end; 

procedure submit; 
begin 
  frmMain.submit;
end;
```

2) prefix `ebMain` with the form's global `frmMain` variable (like you are already doing for `Close()`):

```
procedure submit; 
begin 
  if frmMain.ebMain.Text='exit' then 
    fmMain.Close; 
end;
```

Yes, you would have had to do this in every version of Delphi, including D7.

Comment: Thank you! Guess I never experienced it before.